# Cache option with javascript_include_tag not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm trying to use the cache option with the javascript_include_tag helper like so:
    `javascript_include_tag "test", "test2", :cache => "test"`

Looking at the [rails api documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/JavascriptTagHelpers.html#method-i-javascript_include_tag), I think everything looks alright.

But when I try to use this, I get the error message:
wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)

I'm using Rails 3.1.3

Comment: You need to post more of the error message, preferable the stack trace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Rails 3.1, you do not need :cache any more. The assets pipeline will take care of it.